# addEventListener is not being called if an exception is thrown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, server-sent-events, icws

I am trying to implement [Server-sent-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) communication between my client and my server.

I have implemented it and it works perfectly except when the server return exceptions.

I am not sure why the exception message is not being returned to the client after the exception.

Here is how my listener is written

```
    var evtSource = new EventSource('poll.php');

    evtSource.addEventListener("getMessagingQueue", function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        console.log(data);
        processServerData(data);

    }, false);
```

Below is my PHP code. (ie. `poll.php`) file

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
set_time_limit(0);

header("Content-Type: text/event-stream" . PHP_EOL);
header("Cache-Control: no-cache" . PHP_EOL);

try {

    $sleepTime = 1;
    $url = '';
    $loggedIn = false;

     if( !isDefinedConstents('ICWS_USERNAME', 'ICWS_PASSWORD', 'ICWS_STATION_NAME', 'ICWS_SERVER', 'ICWS_PORT') ){
        throw new exception('Missing Credentials');
    } else {

        $scheme = 'http';
        if(ICWS_SECURED){
            $scheme = 'https';
        }


        $url = sprintf('%s://%s:%s@%s:%s', $scheme, ICWS_USERNAME, ICWS_PASSWORD, ICWS_SERVER, ICWS_PORT);

        //configure the connection
        $conf = new ICWS\Config\Config($url, ICWS_STATION_NAME);    

        //create a new instance of icws

        $icws = new ICWS\Connection($conf); 
        $messaging = new ICWS\Messaging($icws);

        $loggedIn = $icws->isLogged();

    }

    if(!$loggedIn){
        throw new exception('Something Went Wrong when trying to login');
    }

    while($loggedIn){

        $messaging->processMessages();

        $result = array_merge( (array) $messaging->getCallsQueue(), (array) $messaging->getCurrentUserStatusQueue()) ;

        displayResults($result);

        sleep(1);

    }

} catch(Exception $e){

    $result = array('userStatus' => array('statusId' => 'You are not logged in!',
                                       'isLoggedIn' => false,
                                       'icwsDescription' => $e
                                       )
                    );

    displayResults($result);


}


function displayResults($result){

    echo 'event: getMessagingQueue' . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'data: ' . json_encode(  $result ) . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();
}



function isDefinedConstents(){

    $args = func_get_args();

    foreach($args as $v){
        $value = constant($v);
        if( !defined($v) || empty($value) ){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

How do I get the listener to get the message even if the there is exceptions?

**EDITED**
When I execute this code after the addEventListner line

```
evtSource.onerror = function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            };
```

This is what I get

```
error { target: EventSource, isTrusted: true, currentTarget: EventSource, eventPhase: 2, bubbles: false, cancelable: false, defaultPrevented: false, timeStamp: 1435614201283000, originalTarget: EventSource, explicitOriginalTarget: EventSource, NONE: 0 }
```

It seems that the Exception thrown by PHP server cause the entire call to fail.

Comment: it has the same output as if there was not exception. it looks like this `event: getMessagingQueue data: {"userStatus":{"statusId":"You are not logged in!","isLoggedIn":false,"icwsDescription":{}}} `

Comment: @blex the addEventListener looks at the output and send extracts only `data: {"userStatus":{"statusId":"You are not logged in!","isLoggedIn":false,"icwsDescription":{}}}`

Comment: it is not json issue. if it was  then `console.log(e);` should give me something but in my case it gives me nothing. I think the issue i that due to the exception, the entire call fails

Comment: I just updated my question. it seems that the whole call fails when the server throws exceptions

Comment: it is not json issue. If it was then `console.log(e);` should give me something but in my case it gives me nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your Javascript code is having trouble `JSON.parse`ing the PHP exception returned because it is not valid JSON. This will cause an uncaught exception in your Javascript code, ending the execution.

The way to get around this is to throw the exception in a way the Javascript can handle. Instead of throwing the exception, try something like `die("data: ". json_encode(array("exception" => "Missing Credentials.")))`

Also, try surrounding your `JSON.parse()` with a try catch block, and print the exception to the console.

There may also be an uncaught exception being thrown in your `processData` function, but we have no way of knowing without seeing the code.

Comment: it is not json issue. If it was then `console.log(e);` should give me something but in my case it gives me nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding `ob_end_clean();` below the two `header(....` lines